# What language should i study?

Tags: android, web, web-scraping

Hey hello i am new to this world of programming , English is not my first language and i am sorry if i make some mistakes typing. Anyway i am here to ask you people: What language should i study for web scraping ? I have been researching for jobs and there are plenty on demand related to scrape web pages, data entry or web programming. And i also want to know if any web programming language knowledge is it good to start learning about android apps programming.

Thanks for the time and i hope you can understand me.=)

Comment: Wrong site to ask! Not sure which is the right one though... Maybe this? http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mikeauss, start with virtually ANY well known language and go from there. Concepts are more important than technical knowledge. 1. You'll change your mind 10000 times anyway. 2. While you are learning it there'll be more stuff appearing and maybe the most popular language for this now, will be dead in a couple of years. You need to form right mindset rather than learn particular languages.

Comment: So i should learn any language and then start mixing it with another ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, programming takes a lot of studying--especially when you are new.  To do web programming, you need to know a lot of different topics: html, javascript, jquery, and a server side language like php, python, perl, ruby, etc, and you need to know how to use a database like mysql, which requires knowing at least some basic SQL.

python makes web scraping really easy, and it's a good general purpose language, which can be used for anything--including as a server side language.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for answering , i am really confused in what to learn and sometimes don't know where to go and what language to follow

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start programming in Java if you want to do Android. Java is very easy to learn and is a good OOP language to understand in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for answering , i am really confused in what to learn and sometimes don't know where to go and what language to follow

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from 0 with web development first thing is HTML. With this you will see that to make your webs dynamic and more attractive you will need to learn javascript and at least a little of PHP. Maybe when you get here you may try the Wordpress CMS to avoid learning at first MySQL and PHP and play with it, so you can get used to it.
But finally if you really want to be a good developer you should at least know SQL and PHP or other server side languages to be able to communicate with a database.
Moreover if you want to learn to develop android apps you will have to learn Java. If your app needs to communicate with a server your PHP and SQL skills may be really useful then.
But if you start knowing nothing about programming I would start with C++ or Java, and even I would learn a little of C first because the other two langueges are Objected Oriented Programming languages and may be more difficult to understand when begginning.
Since you want to develop for Android, Java is a good starting point but so it is C++ which is quite similar to Objective C (programming language for Iphone).
So get into Java or C++! and be patient!

Comment: Good contribution , thanks for this ERed. Gracias

Comment: So i should have a first project and further projects after so i can try different languages?

Comment: You should focus on one project, either web develoment or android apps. Trying to encompass all together in the begining would be a mistake I think. You should choose between web or app ;)